# Create comments pagination like Disqus comments pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, comments, paginator

I have a comments table that contains the following fields as well as a few other fields(like created_at and updated_at):

```
+====+=========+========+========+
| id | post_id | author | parent |
+====+=========+========+========+
|  1 |       5 |      1 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  2 |       5 |      5 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  3 |       5 |      1 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  4 |       5 |      7 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  5 |       5 |      1 |      4 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  6 |       5 |      3 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  7 |       5 |      5 |      4 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  8 |       5 |      3 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
|  9 |       5 |      1 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| 10 |       5 |      7 |      6 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| 11 |       5 |      3 |      6 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| 12 |       5 |      3 |      4 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
| 13 |       5 |      1 |      4 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+
```

When I render the post that has id = 5 these comments will be rendered like the following:
[image]

The pagination process will be done using Ajax and I want to create a pagination where the comments per page equal to 6 and the page 1 will contain only first 6 comments in the image(from comment_id = 1 to comment_id = 12) there will be a `load more comments` button(like Disqus) that will appear at the bottom of the comment id = 12 when they will click on it then next 6 comments will be loaded and so on and so forth, I just want the SQL and the PHP code.

I want the SQL statements to be as efficient as possible and I don't mind to create other tables if they will make the selection process more efficient.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Good go ahead :)... we are not here to write a code for you... we are just volunteers , if you want to make similar kind of system, then hire someone to do it or show us the code you trying and have problem with. Anybody around here will not write any code for you. We can help you out with issue in code and not to write it from scratch.

Comment: @ArshSingh thank you, here is my current SQL code that doesn't work for this particular situation: SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id ={$post_id} AND approved='1' LIMIT {$offset}, {$rows};